# Query left join without all the right rows from B table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, A and B.
I need all columns from A + 1 column from B in my select.
Unfortunately, B has multiples rows(all identicals) for 1 row in A 
on the join condition.

I tried but I can't isolate one row in A for one row in B with left join for example while keeping my select.

How can I do this query ? Query in ORACLE SQL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: "B has multiples rows(all identicals) for 1 row in A on the join condition" sounds like a bad, not normalized datamodel. You may want to change this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for `outer apply`.  The structure of the query looks like this:

```
select a.*, b.col
from a outer apply
     (select top 1 b.col
      from b
      where b.? = a.?
     ) b;
```

Normally, you would only use `top 1` with `order by`.  In this case, it doesn't seem to make a difference which row you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by` on all columns from `A`, and then use an aggregate (like `max` or `min`) to pick any of the identical B values:

```
select  a.*
,       b.min_col1
from    TableA a
left join
        (
        select  a_id
        ,       min(col1) as min_col1
        from    TableB
        group by
                a_id
        ) b
on      b.a_id = a.id
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use cross apply in my Oracle Sql Developer unfortunately.
And for the solution below with group by, there are 50 columns in table A, is there not another solution to make it less redundant ?

Comment: You can move the `group by` to a subquery, edited in answer

Comment: Sorry but it is still not working,
select  a_id
        ,       min(col1) as min_col1
is showing invalid identifier when modified to suit my table names